# Best way to download files synchronously (downloadManager)

Tags: android, recursion, stack-overflow, synchronous, android-download-manager

I tried to download some files synchronously in my main thread.
Also, I created a recursive method which call itself at each receive callback (with progressdialog increment) but after 200/250 recursive calls, I had a a stack overflow error. It seems it's not the best practise for this.
After, I tried a simply for loop but the download isn't finished beetween each loop so the unregisterReceiver wasn't call, which make a leak.

This is my loop code :

```
    private void loadMediaFiles(final ArrayList<MediaAPIModel> mediaAPIModels, final ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    for(int i = 0; i < mediaAPIModels.size(); i++) {
        if (mediaAPIModels.get(i).getUrl() != null) {
            if (!FileManager.getInstance().getFileFromLocal(context, mediaAPIModels.get(i).getUrl(), false)) {
                String name = mediaAPIModels.get(i).getUrl().substring(mediaAPIModels.get(i).getUrl().lastIndexOf("/") + 1); //on s?pare le nom du fichier du reste de l'url
                Log.d(TAG, CallAPI.mBaseUrl + mediaAPIModels.get(i).getUrl());
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(CallAPI.mBaseUrl + mediaAPIModels.get(i).getUrl()));
                request.setDescription(context.getResources().getString(R.string.downloading) + " name");
                request.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                request.setMimeType(name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".")));
                // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("test" + File.separatorChar + "doc", name);
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                manager.enqueue(request);

                context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                        progressDialog.setProgress(progressDialog.getProgress() + 1);
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "doc already exists");
                progressDialog.setProgress(progressDialog.getProgress() + 1);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "finish");
            progressDialog.setProgress(progressDialog.getProgress() + 1);
        }
    }
    if (progressDialog.isShowing())
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    startProcess();
}
```

Sorry if my english is bad ^^'

Comment: you should never download files on the main thread, why not use a async task

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to unregister your BroadcastReceiver as soon as the download is finished. It just has to be cleaned up before the app is removed from view. Because of this, it's usually best practice to unregister your receiver in your Activity's `onPause()` method so it will simply be cleaned up any time the app is moved to the background or finished completely.

As for your progress update during the download, `DownloadManager` has an automatic display for showing the progress of a download. You just have to call `request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);`

If you are wanting to implement your own progress UI, you can query `DownloadManager`'s internal byte count of your download that is stored in `DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR` and then cancel your UI element when you receive a notification in your BroadcastReceiver for `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`

As you can see, there are a lot of ways to do what it is you are trying to do. It sounds like you need to read up a bit more on the DownloadManager documentation so that you can fully take advantage of the conveniences that class provides.